# Chartjs - how to change the notation of doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have created a doughnut chart using the bellow code

```js
   var randomScalingFactor = function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    };

    var config = {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                    window.chartColors.red,
                    window.chartColors.orange,
                    window.chartColors.yellow,
                    window.chartColors.green,
                    window.chartColors.blue,
                ],
                label: 'Dataset 1'
            }],
            labels: [
                "Red",
                "Orange",
                "Yellow",
                "Green",
                "Blue"
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <div id="canvas-holder" style="width:40%">
        <canvas id="chart-area" />
    </div>
```

And will show a graph like bellow,

[image]

Is there any option is there to change the graph notation like the bellow image?
I was try to check the documentation,and i don't find anything to change this.
[image]

Comment: With google charts, this is easy doable with `options.legend: { position: 'labeled' }`. Maybe chart.js has something similar.

Comment: but there is no doughnut option found,is there?

Comment: If you mean making google pie charts as a doughnut, then yes, you can  do with by setting a hole inside a normal pie chart with `options: { pieHole: 0.5 };`. I do not think it will be too hard to convert to those graphs, giving your current data.

Comment: @CatalinIancu thanks for the hint.i made it https://jsfiddle.net/vtfv99wc/ . you are great

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to make use of the `onAnimationComplete` method to loop through each `datasets` and `metadata` to reconstruct the tooltip values to make them as values.

Here is a demo,

https://jsfiddle.net/c8Lk2381/246/

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="chart" height="450" width="640"></canvas>
```

**Javascript**

```
tooltip.transition(Chart.helpers.easingEffects.linear).draw();
            }, self);
        }, self);
    }
},
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
                2,
                4,
                7,
                1,
                6,
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                "Red",
                "Green",
                "Yellow",
                "Grey",
                "Purple",
            ],
        }],
        labels: [
            "Red",
            "Green",
            "Yellow",
            "Grey",
            "Purple"
        ]
    },
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var doughnutchart = new Chart(ctx, doughnutChartConfig);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you add the relevant code in answer? You can copy from the fiddle and paste it here.